# Matplotlib: How to color errorbars the same color as bar using pylab.bar()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to be able to color my errorbars the same color as the bar color. However, this is not happening based on my code below.

```
# Plot
x = sig['Glycan Name_Seal']
y_seal = sig['Average RFU_Seal']
yerr_seal = sig['StDev_Seal']

y_human = sig['Average RFU_Human']
yerr_human = sig['StDev_Human']

barwidth=0.5
alpha=1

plt.figure(0, figsize=(18,6))
plt.bar(left=sig.index, 
        color=['blue', 'blue'], height=y_seal, width=barwidth, yerr=yerr_seal, label='Seal', alpha=alpha)
plt.bar(left=sig.index + barwidth, 
        color=['red', 'red'], height=y_human, width=barwidth, yerr=yerr_human, label='Human', alpha=alpha)
plt.ylim(0,2500)
plt.ylabel('Average RFU', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Glycan Number', fontsize=14)
plt.xlim(0, 56)
plt.title('Pre-Complexed p-value < 0.01', fontsize=18)
plt.legend(fontsize=16)

# Add a vertical line to distinguish alpha(2,3) and alpha(2,6)
plt.plot([1, 1], [0, 2500], color="black", linewidth=2)
plt.plot([9, 9], [0, 2500], color="black", linewidth=2)
plt.plot([11, 11], [0, 2500], color="black", linewidth=2)

# Add the texts greek alpha(2,3) and alpha(2,6)
plt.annotate(r"$\alpha$(2,6)", (3.5, 2250), fontsize=14)
plt.annotate(r"$\alpha$(2,3)", (29, 2250), fontsize=14)
plt.annotate("asialoglycan", xy=(0.25, 1950), xytext=(2, 1950), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", linewidth=2), fontsize=14)
plt.annotate(r"$\alpha$(2,3) and $\alpha$(2,6)", xy=(10, 1850), xytext=(12, 1850), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", linewidth=2), fontsize=14)

plt.savefig('Average RFU Plot.pdf')
```

What comes out is that the `Seal` data is displayed with blue bars and blue error bars, but the `Human` data is displayed with red bars and green error bars.

Is it possible to make the `Human` data display with red error bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `ecolor='red'` in the offending plot. I would recommend setting `ecolor='blue'` in your first plot as well, since it looks like you are just getting blue error bars there because that is the first color that they cycle through. See [the documentation for plt.bar](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html) for more details.

This is done in the call to `plt.bar` as:

```
plt.bar(..., ecolor='red', ...)
```